# Getting error when creating external table on Oracle through SQL Server PolyBase

Tags: oracle, polybase, oracle18c, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to create an external table on Oracle using SQL Server PolyBase

At the beginning I was getting error

> ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

After adding below line to sqlnet.ora

> SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8

The previous error disappeared and  I started getting below error

> [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-01017:
>   invalid username/password; logon denied

I have created the datasource using below credential

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ora_cred WITH IDENTITY = 'SYSTEM', Secret = 'SYSTEM';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE ora_ds
WITH ( LOCATION = 'oracle://xeonserver:1521',
-- PUSHDOWN = ON | OFF,
CREDENTIAL = ora_cred)

create external table Student
(
    id int,
    name varchar(25)
)
with (
    location = 'XE.SYSTEM.Student',
    data_source = ora_ds
)
```

I can connect to Oracle instance `(XE)` using `SYSTEM/SYSTEM` so I don't know why I get the error.

I'm using SQL Server 2019 CTP-2 and Oracle 18 Express.

Comment: Have you tried this with a later SQL 2019 release? There were some issues with PolyBase against Oracle in some of the CTP's. I am running equivalent code in SQL Server 2019 RTM.

Comment: Yes. Using final version I was able to resolve the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of the logs my guess is that the user you are using to create the table doesn't have permissions needed to create a table in the database its connecting to. Check in that DB and give it schema ownership.

Comment: I'm sure that SYSTEM/SYSTEM can create table, because I have created couple of table using that user directly in Oracle (using sqlplus)

Comment: Permissions are different when you are connecting cross-database.